# Custom framework fails to load in iOS simulator (wrong architecture)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to build a Cocoa Touch Framework for iOS8 which will eventually be embedded in apps and submitted to the App store so it's important that the release build contains ONLY armv7 but the debug build must run in the simulator too. As such, I've been following [this tutorial](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios8-remix/) and I'm hitting upon a runtime error when trying to run an application in the simulator with the framework embedded:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
  Referenced from: /Users/jay/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/97715157-EABB-4F38-8CA0-62768358DDD6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4856FC75-6C5B-4F7E-91A9-70CA1863D130/Test.app/TestFramework
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: /Users/jay/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/97715157-EABB-4F38-8CA0-62768358DDD6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4856FC75-6C5B-4F7E-91A9-70CA1863D130/Test.app/Frameworks/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

However, when I browse to the framework binary it's complaining about

```
(/Users/jay/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/97715157-EABB-4F38-8CA0-62768358DDD6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4856FC75-6C5B-4F7E-91A9-70CA1863D130/Test.app/)
```

and run `xcrun lipo -info TestFramework` I get the output `Non-fat file: TestFramework is architecture: i386` so I'm kinda lost at where to go now. It runs fine on an actual iOS device.

Comment: "submitted to the App store" and "contains ONLY armv7" are mutually-exclusive.

Comment: Sorry, armv7 / arm64. Whatever, just no simulator architectures.

Comment: OK I would assume that this relates to how your Xcode app target is made dependent on your framework target.  If this is set in the *Build Phase* correctly then Xcode will build the correct architecture for the app (i.e. device or simulator).  I think then all you need to do is copy it to the correct place in the app bundle (the iOS app bundle structure is much less formal than the OSX app bundle structure, but it still needs doing).  This would probably need a custom script in the *Build Phases* tab.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - from the tutorial, it should find the framework version pertaining to debug or release:

$(PROJECT_DIR)/lib/$(CONFIGURATION)"

and the debug one should work with both. The thing I'm hung up on is that the file it's loading definitely contains i386 libs only (should include armv7 too) yet somehow only works on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and your comments, the most likely cause of this is that you are building your framework for 32bit and linking it into a 64bit application.  If that's not the case, please provide the entire text of your crash log.

You should build your framework 4way-fat:

```
  i386/iphonesimulator
  x86_64/iphonesimulator
  armv7/iphoneos
  arm64/iphoneos
```

In order to make it 4-way fat, you'll need to manually lipo-together your i386/x86_64 sim build with your armv7/arm64 device build.  Building 4-way fat with two different (from Xcode's perspective) platforms is not supported by Xcode.

**New in Xcode 11:** You can use an `xcframework` to support these kinds of scenarios! No more lipo hacks required. You can find the details in [WWDC 2019 Session 416](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a custom framework containing views that I use in the Interface Builder and I got this error on the Interface Builder build phase.

Running `pod install` fixed it.